# Names of Allah الواجد and الماجد

Tags: arabic, asma-ul-husna

Can we say Allah is الواجد who has وجود and Allah is الماجد who is موجود ? Because i think وجود comes from الواجد and موجود comes from الماجد ! Because these words have very similarities that's why i'm asking to you kindly correct me if i'm wrong ?

Comment: This certainly wrong ماجد is related to مجد.

Comment: But موجود comes from م ج د which is similar to ماجد and وجود comes from و ج د which is similar to واجد !